# Sitecore Xpress -Developer missing

Tags: sitecore

I have installed Sitecore Xpress version on Virtual machine (MS Server 2008 R2). I have notice that sitecore only works within Firefox. Either using IE8 (or IE9) or Chrome not offer me an option to select appropriate User Interface. Furthermore, all icons are missing when login into the Sitecore, also I am not able to choose any action (button click not works at all). 
Beside that, I was wondering why I am not able to see Developer user interface as option before login? Is it possible inside Xpress version at all?

Comment: This issue almost resolved. Installed IE tab on Chrome lead to proper functionality. It seems that IE8 is not supported for old version of Sitecore. IE tab works on IE7 compatibility mode. With Firefox I have noticed missing ribbon bar when RTF editor open. On the other hand with Chrome locking button is moved and not link to appropriate items (locking icons moved two field bellow than expected)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used Sitecore Express on IE8. It is working perfectly fine.

Which Operating System you are using?

If you are using server 2008 then you have to lower the security level for your Intranet. 
OR you can add your site in to Trusted Sites.
Both Options are in Internet Explorer Tools -> Options -> Security

On Login Screen of Sitecore Express Click Advance options.
You will get 6 Options

1. Desktop
2. Content Editor
3. Page Editor
4. Preview
5. Workbox
6. Developer Center

Comment: Thank you Maulik, your answer solves my IE8 sitecore issue. :)